# How to use apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([])

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

How to merge nodes in a query with `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([])` and then do something about the merged node?
When I use this:

```
WITH w2, minW, minW {.*} as snapshot
call apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([minW,w2]) YIELD reW
SET reW.first_seen =...
```

This error is thrown: `Unknown procedure output: reW`

If instead of using `reW`, `minW` is used, the error says that the variable has already been decleared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procedures declare the variables yielded by them. You can either check for the yielded variable in the documentation (which in this case won't help, it's not shown for this procedure in APOC docs, I'll try to get a fix in), or call `apoc.help()` and pass in the procedure name, like:

```
call apoc.help('apoc.refactor.mergeNodes')
```

The signature output should show the variable yielded. In this case, it's `node`, so use `YIELD node`, though you can alias it using `as` however you like.

Comment: Apparently the merge violates the constraint I set. Is there any way around that?

Comment: you mean something like this https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/397

Comment: No it seems more like something which would come up when neo4j is trying to create a repeated node according to constraint. The error output is this:  Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes`: Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.ConstraintViolationException: Node 50783 already exists with label Wallet and property "primWallAddr"=[1CzbWrLswUJVCJZjHecp6Q4ce6VrGNAXoT]